# fetching photos by date - iOS

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, phasset

Disclaimer –I’m new to iOS and to this forum too. 
I have a need to get pictures taken in specific dates (let’s say  January 9-January 12) . I don't want to go over all the photos in the photo library for enhance the app performance. I am looking for some public API to full fill my requirement. Does apple `Photo Framework` supports fetching photo collection by date? Is `PHFetchOptions` the solution and if so what is the right way to use it ?

Answer (score 10):

You can create a predicate to specify the dates:

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];

fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creationDate > %@ AND creationDate < %@", startDate, endDate];

PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];
```